# Why do I get an error deleting a dynamic pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, dynamic, new-operator, delete-operator

Please don't come and say "jUst read the error", it doesn't specify it, that's why Im asking here.

```
int main()
{
    int* p, * q;
    int a = 10;
    p = new int;
    p = &a;
delete p;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself what `p` is pointing to when you call `delete`.

Comment: Your assigning the address of a stack allocated variable to p.

Comment: There is nothing like a dynamic pointer. It's the memory which is dynamically allocated `p = new int;` but in next line you pointed `p` to a memory on stack.

Comment: `p` is not a *dynamic pointer* it is pointing to an automatic (stack) variable.

Comment: thank you, but what can I do to fix it? Or how can I delete?

Comment: It's a common misconception that *pointers* need deleting, but they don't – it is the objects they point to that might need deleting, but only if they were created dynamically. (This is most likely caused by experienced programmers talking about "deleting the pointer", because it's shorter than "deleting the object that the pointer points to" and we have learned that the phrase really means something else.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
p = new int
```

In this line, you dynamically allocate the memory that you need to `delete`.

```
p = &a
```

But in this line, you are not allocating new memory, you are pointing `p` at stack memory, and leaking the memory that you previously allocated.

Comment: thank you, but as I said what can I do to fix it? Or how can I delete?

Comment: @ekremturkoglu: you should `delete p;` before `p = &a`.

Comment: You should only talk about storage duration and not about stack and heap. An object with dynamic storage duration could also be located on the stack (placement new) and would need to be deleted due to that.